# Eclipse can't find compiler after update

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, updates

I have updated the JRE of my Eclipse and selected the new one in the "Installed JREs" tab, but I can't find it in the "Compiler" tab so I can't use it. I want to be able to use *lambda* expressions, and for that I need the compiler to figure out that Java8 exists.

**Images of my Issue:**

[image]
[image]

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: If that link doesn't work, here are backups 
NOCompiler: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_x9cY3Z6Ws0DioPoHRe-RF82uUVPclHE -----HasJRE: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14fwGtOJDmn2UvXk_2pR5jqT4XnauBNrm

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this? Versions before Eclipse Luna don't support Java 8.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's older than that. Got to get a new one then, I guess

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler. If the _Compile compliance level_ drop-down does not contain _1.8_, _9_ and _10_, [upgrade your Eclipse IDE](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F). Besides that, the first screenshot shows _Window > Preferences..._ which is used for new projects, for existing project you have to change the compiler settings in _Project > Properties..._. In the second screenshot choose a JDK, not only a JRE. Otherwise you cannot see the source code of the JRE (e. g. of `java.lang.String` etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check your current version of the eclipse.It might not be the latest**